# hibernate HQL subtract from subquery QuerySyntaxException

Tags: hibernate, exception, subquery, hql

I'm trying to write this `HQL` query that will work for both Sybase and Derby databases. Here is the pseudo code for the query:

```
from MY_TABLE as t
where (t.Val = :val) 
and (t.Val2 > 
    ( select max(tt.Val2)
    from MY_TABLE as tt
    where tt.Val = :val) - 2);
```

When I run this with hibernate as a `HQL` query it fails with a `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node` but if I execute the query as SQL it is successful. I've narrowed it down to it not liking subtracting a value from the results of a subquery but I haven't been able to find anything on google explaining how to fix this.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? For now I'm just going to do it as SQL to move forward but my curiosity really wants to know how to do it in HQL.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to write this HQL query that will work for both Sybase and
>   Derby databases

You don't write HQL which conforms to the requirements of any specific database platform. HQL is an abstraction which references properties and classes in your mapped object graph.

Hibernate will take care of generating SQL which conforms to the underlying database platform using the mappings you have provided it with and the configured dialect.

Comment: No idea why that was downvoted, re-based to zero with an upvote! Probably a spurious click since there is no denying why we use HQL.

Comment: Although your answer is informative it does not answer the ultimate question that was asked. That is why your answer was downgraded. The original question was: Why can't I subtract a constant value from the results of a sub-query using HQL when it works using SQL? And what is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?